# Android connection error : Gralloc pipe failed

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to send data to MySQL data base but taking this error.

```
W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed

[ 12-26 22:08:05.136  2393: 2393 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa998dd80, tid 2393
```

Here is my android code

```
public RequestQueue reguestQueue;
public String insertUrl = "10.0.2.2/beacon/insertBeacon.php"; // local ip adresi yaz

 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private void startTime() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // buraya ne yapmak istiyorsan o kodu yaz.. Kodun sonlandıktan sonra 1 saniye sonra tekrar çalışacak şekilde handler tekrar çalışacak.
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("firstname","Serkan");
                    parameters.put("lastname","BAYRAM");
                    parameters.put("age","19");

                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            reguestQueue.add(request);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
        InputStream iss = null;
        int code;
        int done = 0;
        String result = null;

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", "Serkan"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", "BAYRAM"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", "19"));

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("10.0.2.2/beacon/insertBeacon.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            iss = entity.getContent();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("pass 2", "Connection Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(iss,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            iss.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

            if(code==1){
                done = 1;  //values inserted successfully
            }
            else
                done = 0;  //values not inserted successfully
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

return 1 or 0 from `insertBeacon.php` in json format